# Remove all selected items from multiple selects using asmselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asmselect

I have multiple asmselect 'select multiple' form inputs on a page I'm developing. I'd like a 'clear' button that resets these to their initial, nothing selected state. I've tried variations of:

```
$('.asmSelect option[selected]').removeAttr("selected");
```

With no luck. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector will help:

```
$('.asmSelect :selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

For example, select a few things and hit *Clear*: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QVzB8/

Comment: This is pretty much it, bar 1 crucial line for asmSelect: $('.asmSelect').change(); which fires a change event to each substituted select, causing all the selects to propagate the clear from the hidden, original select multiples to those created by the library.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.asmSelect').each(function(){this.selectedIndex = -1});
```

You could try that.

#### Edit: Tested

works. You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/P6NeU/)

Comment: Works for selects, yes, but not asmSelect (which is a jQuery library)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/9Ejdz/2/

Answer (score 0):

After getting stuck with this issue for some 90 minutes I came up with this simple yet effective solution: just pretent asmListItemRemove was clicked like this:

```
$('.asmListItemRemove').trigger('click');
```

Me happy :)

PS.: The solution marked as correct did NOT work for me, as ist took the data out of the select mode but did'nt remove the selectors. When I removed them by jquery .remove() or .hide() the targeted prop would not be selectable next time the select was clicked.

Comment: Your solution worked for me as well. Thanks for the tip!